# Pandas export Excel to CSV - merg cell

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to save excel to CSV but make up the cells

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

in_xls = 'excel01.xlsx'
sheet = 'Arkusz1'

with pd.ExcelFile(in_xls, engine="openpyxl") as ex:
  excel = pd.read_excel(ex, sheet, header=None)

excel.to_csv('excel_out.csv', index=False)
```

My excel file:
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZQ-5WiTfJ3dDRU_q9RcuVTyBOXwTunHK/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114226381398446922584&rtpof=true&sd=true)

as a dictionary use `pd.DatFrame(d)`

```
d = {0: {0: 'TEST\nPpp666', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}, 1: {0: 39191012, 1: 39191012, 2: 39191012, 3: 39191012, 4: 39191012, 5: 39191012}, 2: {0: 5906194003016, 1: 5906194003023, 2: 5906194003030, 3: 5906194003054, 4: 5906194003085, 5: 5906194003115}, 3: {0: 'DN-113H181-0019018', 1: 'DN-113H182-0019018', 2: 'DN-113H183-0019018', 3: 'DN-113H185-0019018', 4: 'DN-113H188-0019018', 5: 'DN-113H18T-K019018'}, 4: {0: 'Pierwszy, drugi\nTrzeci\nCzwarty', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}, 5: {0: 'czarny', 1: 'czerwony', 2: 'niebieski', 3: 'biały ', 4: 'żółty', 5: 'Tęcza 5 kolorów'}, 6: {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100, 5: 20}, 7: {0: '19mmx18m', 1: '19mmx18m', 2: '19mmx18m', 3: '19mmx18m', 4: '19mmx18m', 5: '19mmx18m'}, 8: {0: '5,80', 1: '5,80', 2: '5,80', 3: '5,80', 4: '5,80', 5: '29,40'}}
```

My output file csv:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
"TEST
Ppp666",39191012,5906194003016,DN-113H181-0019018,"Pierwszy, drugi
Trzeci
Czwarty",czarny,100,19mmx18m,5.8
,39191012,5906194003023,DN-113H182-0019018,,czerwony,100,19mmx18m,5.8
,39191012,5906194003030,DN-113H183-0019018,,niebieski,100,19mmx18m,5.8
,39191012,5906194003054,DN-113H185-0019018,,biały ,100,19mmx18m,5.8
,39191012,5906194003085,DN-113H188-0019018,,żółty,100,19mmx18m,5.8
,39191012,5906194003115,DN-113H18T-K019018,,Tęcza 5 kolorów,20,19mmx18m,29.4
```

I would like to get a CSV file

[image]

Comment: you need to add the format that you get when you read the excel file into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Can you give an example, I do not understand. Thanks

Comment: see [mcve] and [ask] you need to create an example we can reproduce in our own environment. at the moment you've shared a picture which we cannot create an example from. Please take some time to read guidance for new users.

Comment: Are these data sufficient?

Comment: from your google sheet `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t',header=None)` then `df = df.ffill(axis=0)` i think `ffill` will be enough for you

Comment: Thank you very much, but I see that this is not a simple topic if we have different files with different columns